# Как сделать запрос из 2х таблиц по максимальному значению колонки во второй таблице?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

У меня такая задача:

Есть таблица `cp_partners`. В ней есть поле `id`. `id` - обозначает уникальный номер партнера.

Есть таблица со скидками партнера `cp_partners_sales`. Каждый партнер имеет 5 записей скидок. Вот структура таблицы:

[image: Структура таблицы]

В этой таблице номер партнера это `idpartner`.

Мне нужно получить список `id` партнеров, отсортированный по скидкам от большего к меньшему.

Я пробовал делать так:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cp_partners AS a 
JOIN cp_partners_sales AS b 
WHERE a.top = 1 
    AND a.is_seen = 1 
    AND a.id = b.idpartner 
GROUP BY b.idpartner 
ORDER BY b.percent DESC
```

Но этот запрос не работает корректно.

Как мне отредактировать запрос?

Comment: *Мне нужно получить список id партнеров, отсортированный по скидкам от большего к меньшему.* У каждого партнёра 5 скидок. По какой сортировать-то?

Comment: по максмальной скидке наверное

Comment: у каждого партнера максимум 5 скидок.  С каждого партнера надо взять максимальное значение. И всех партнеров сортируем по максимальному значению

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проверять негде, но как то так?

```
SELECT p.id
      , p.title   # поле с названием
      , max(ps.percent) as maxDiscount
FROM cp_partners AS p
LEFT JOIN cp_partners_sales AS ps ON (ps.idpartner = p.id)
WHERE p.top = 1 
      AND p.is_seen = 1 
GROUP BY p.id, p.title
ORDER BY maxDiscount DESC, p.title
```

левый джойн, на случай если у некоторых партнеров нет скидок. сортировка по скидке, и названию.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Работает! подредактировал под себя